# Python - Text file into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I have recently began working with text files in python (how to return them in different ways, how to produce a text file and so on) and I discovered that a text file can also be returned as a dicitonary in python and I was wondering how one could achieve that. Let's say i have a text file including some types of currencies and their buy and sell values and i wanted to return them in some sort of a dictionary. The text file would for example include:

```
Num Date____ Bank Type_______ NCu CCu Buy___________ Sell__________
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 840 USD 0001,074800000 0001,050800000
```

and would return some sort of dictionary, that would include the currency as the keys and a tuple of its buy and sell values as the key. So the upper text file would produce:

```
'USD': (1.0748, 1.0508)}
```

Help on how to achieve this sort of return in python would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could read the txt file as a csv delimited by space/tab, using csv DictReader 


https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 2):

Let's process the file line per line, create a dictionary, split the line, and create entries, converting text to floats in the process (commas have to be replaced by dots)

```
test="""Num Date____ Bank Type_______ NCu CCu Buy___________ Sell__________
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 840 USD 0001,074800000 0001,050800000
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 840 CHF 0002,074800000 0004,050800000
""".splitlines().__iter__()

d = dict()

next(test)  # skip title line
for line in test:
    toks = line.split()
    if len(toks)==8:
        d[toks[5]] = (float(toks[6].replace(",",".")),float(toks[7].replace(",",".")))

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'USD': (1.0748, 1.0508), 'CHF': (2.0748, 4.0508)}
```

That's just for a standalone test. When running with a file, just replace the string by:

```
with open("input.txt") as test:
```

and it will act the same, but with a file as input.

(or use the `csv` module but 1) that seems to be overkill for your case, and 2) we don't know if the separators are tabs, space, or more than 1 space/tab. `str.split` handles that too so I'd stick with it until fields containing spaces appear :))

Answer (score 0):

text:

```
Num Date____ Bank Type_______ NCu CCu Buy___________ Sell__________
001 20161130 NLB_ individuals 840 USD 0001,074800000 0001,050800000
```

main.py:

```
exchange_rates = {}
with open("text") as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        data = line.split(" ")
        ccu = data[5]
        buy = float(data[6].replace(",", "."))
        sell = float(data[7].replace(",", "."))
        exchange_rates[ccu] = (buy, sell)

print(exchange_rates)
```

You split each line at the spaces `" "` into a list containing the data:

```
data = line.split(" ")
```

Then you have to convert the string `"0001,07400"` into a `float`. One can use `float( )` for this, but this needs that `"0001,07400"` is transformed into `"0001.0740"` first:

```
float(data[6].replace(",", "."))
```

This is *simple* file parsing. You have to be cautious though, when data is missing (ie 7 instead of 8 entries) or is formatted differently (`0001.074` instead of `0001,074`) or or or... For such cases you might have to make extra distinctions.